# Forked a repo after submitting pull requests but before they were accepted

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

1. I submitted two pull requests to a documentation repo (I will call it Repo-A).  *[Note: All changes are made directly to the master branch for Repo-A; the git-flow methodology is not used.]*
2. The pull requests are currently outstanding at Repo-A (not accepted, not rejected; just waiting for attention from owner of Repo-A).
3. I forked Repo-A, so now I have MyRepo-B.
4. At GitHub, Repo-A is shown as having two open pull requests.
5. At GitHub, MyRepo-B is shown as having *no* open pull requests.  Instead, I see the two pull requests shown as *patch-1* and *patch-2* in the GitKraken UI:

[image]

My question: How can I merge the two patches to the master branch on MyRepo-B?

(PS: I don't care about what happens on Repo-A.)

Comment: It should be something like `git checkout master` followed by, `git merge patch-1` and `git merge patch-2`

Comment: @Hackerman What are the two things called patch-1 and patch-2? Are they branches? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, they are branches :)

Comment: @Hackerman Could you please tell me how to do the merge using GitKraken? Thanks.

Comment: Check the `GitKraken Merge Tool` part https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-repositories/branching-and-merging

Comment: @Hackerman If I use the CLI, do I need to do anything else after the git merge patch-1?  (e.g. commit or push...)

Comment: If you do it from the command line, you still need to commit and push those changes...from the GitKraken client, it seems that ti gives you the choice to do that automagically.

Comment: Done @Sabuncu ...did you visited Chile? How do you know the word `Bacán`? xD

Comment: @Hackerman https://theculturetrip.com/south-america/chile/articles/18-chilean-slang-phrases-youll-need-on-your-trip/  I hope to visit some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line:

```
git checkout master 
git merge patch-1
git merge patch-2
git commit -am "merge patch 1 and 2 branches into master"
git push -u
```

From the `GitKraken` client, you can use the `GitKraken Merge Tool`,

> https://support.gitkraken.com/working-with-repositories/branching-and-merging

Comment: Note: I did not do a commit.  Doing a push worked, and GitHub repo was updated. Don't know why.